# Is there a proper way to do the equivalent of onRestoreInstanceState when calling a Activity for result?

Tags: android, onactivityresult, onrestoreinstancestate

I'm currently retrieving a photo from the camera or the gallery, such as

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Which works fine. It's the behaviour of the current activity that is kinda misleading.

It calls onSaveInstanceState fine, but when you get the callback onActivityResult it never calls onRestoreInstanceState, now I understand the lifecycle, but this seems counter intuitive.  You really have to know how things execute with respect to onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState, or do you ignore that and use perm storage in onPause/onResume.  I've seen explanations of onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState preceeding onPause/onResume, respectively. So it seems the Activity lifecycle doesn't really handle this.  Intuitively you would think that if onSaveInstanceState is called that onRestoreInstanceState should be called.  In complex activities, I'm almost ready to write my own.  What's the best way to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: do what you want to do in onRestoreInstanceState to onActivityResult. because onRestoreInstanceState called when your activity was destroyed before when calling other activity. in this case, you call startActivityForResult, and your activity is keep alive

Comment: Yes but onRestoreInstanceState is not called for startActivityForResult, making what I did in onSaveInstanceState useless when I call startActivityForResult.  It's not a matter of if I called startActivityForResult, I do. It's for the scenario of calling startActivityForResult onSaveInstanceState is basically useless since it's counter part, onRestoreInstanceState,  is NEVER called.